# whats wrong with this getJson call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, getjson

here is my jQuery

```
$.getJSON('/users/delete_preapproval', { 
  preapproval: $(this).attr('id'), id: $(this).attr('id') }, 
function(data) {
complete: function(){
     console.log('ssss');
  }
});
```

All works well and the server processes the request but the complete is not working...I am not getting my console.log displaying. I basically need an on complete or on success to fire after a successful ajax call

EDIT: here is my entire click event:

```
$('.delete_preapproval').click(function(e){
    var count = $(this).closest('.request_count').attr('data');
    if(count > 0){
        if(count == 1){
            var plural = 'request';
        }else{
            var plural = 'requests';
        }           
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this preapproval you have ' + count + ' active ' + plural)){
                $.getJSON('/users/delete_preapproval', { 
                    preapproval: $(this).attr('id'), 
                    id: $(this).attr('id') 
                }, 
                function(data) {
                     console.log('ssss');
                });

     }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        $.getJSON('/users/delete_preapproval', { preapproval: $(this).attr('id'), id: $(this).attr('id') }, function(data) {
      window.location.reload();
        });
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should actually get a syntax error. Remove `complete:` :

```
$.getJSON('/users/delete_preapproval', { 
    preapproval: $(this).attr('id'), 
    id: $(this).attr('id') 
}, 
function(data) {
     console.log('ssss');
});
```

`complete:` is creating a [label *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) at this line. Removing the label would be:

```
function(data) {
    function(){
        console.log('ssss');
    } 
}
```

You see that that inner function is never executed when the outer function is called (apart from the syntax error).

**Update:** Also make sure that the data you return is proper JSON. Otherwise jQuery cannot parse it and will not call the callback.

Comment: still no ssss ...i updated my question with the entire jquery call

Comment: just in case your wondering it is def making it in the     if(count > 0){
condition

Comment: @Tamer: What is the response of the server? Is it proper JSON? Maybe jQuery cannot parse it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the complete: and the function call after it. So something more like:

```
$.getJSON('/users/delete_preapproval', { 
  preapproval: $(this).attr('id'), id: $(this).attr('id') }, 
function(data) {
     console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "/users/delete_preapproval",           
    dataType: 'json',
  data: {preapproval : $(this).attr('id'), id : $(this).attr('title')},
    complete: function () { 
        console.log('ssss');
    }           
});
```

That should work...